# PickleDb cannot retrieve object from database

Tags: python, django

I'm using PickleDb for saving state of a Django app. The problem is that while I can save to the database I cannot retrieve from it. Here's my (simplified) code that actually works great when I run it locally on the Django development server.

```
import pickledb

gamesdb = pickledb.load('games.db', False)

def play(request):

    game = Game()
    game.players = ['Adam', 'Eve']

    gamesdb.set(game.uid, game)

    return render_to_response('index.html', {})

def current_player(request, game_uid):

    game = gamesdb.get(game_uid)
    current_player = game.players[0] 

    return HttpResponse(play_data, mimetype='application/json')
```

When I try to retrieve `game.players[0]` it tells me that `game` is `None`

Comment: are you sure that you actually set `gamesdb[game_uid]` before you tried to call it for the current player?

Comment: Hi Jeff, yes I'm sure it gets set as the play method takes care of the setup for the game. Also as I mentioned it works on the local server. Might it be because it's single-threaded?

Comment: It's even stranger than I thought the current_player view actually returns the correct json data when called by itself.

Comment: I don't understand what your last comment: if it's returning the correct json data, when are you getting the error that game is None?

Comment: If I take the URL and paste it in the browser as such http://example.com/current_player/7bfb26e1bc90bdbc7e011460055f62a57e259979/ it returns ["Eve", "c11373ce3fd65a1d295f55e195d32b7baf237b97"]

If, instead this gets called by the javascript code via an ajax call I get the error that tells me that the game instance I'm trying to retrieve from gamesdb is None

Comment: Jeff, I think you're right I was calling all ajax requests with POST rather than GET as they were. This worked on the dev server which is why I didn't notice the issue before.

Comment: I'm going to close this question and start a new one. PickleDb is clearly not the problem. Going to post the full stack of calls I'm using.